# Como não mostrar elemento img aonde src seja igual a nulo

Tags: php, html

Estou a fazer um sistema aonde o usuário pode postar imagens, textos, etc...porém no sistema toda imagem postada deve ser upada ao servidor e o usuário pode excluí-las.

Com a exclusão da imagem do servidor logo os posts que contém tal imagem apresentam o erro 404.

Sei que é possível mostrar uma imagem padrão para imagens não encontradas via `.htaccess` porém o que quero é não mostrar nem erro nem imagem padrão, simplesmente não mostrar o `img`.

O sistema esta estruturado assim:

Página `home.php`

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
session_start();
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if(isset($_GET['last_msg_id'])){
   $last_msg_id = $_GET['last_msg_id'];
}
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
   $action=$_GET['action'];
}else{ 
   $action = ''; 
}

if($action != "get"){
?>
   <div id="coisaEstranha" style="margin-top:2%;">
                 <?php include('load_first.php'); ?>
                 <div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
            <?php }else{ include('load_second.php');exit();}?>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
    function last_msg_funtion(){
      if($('#last_msg_loader img').length){
         return;
      }
      var ID = $(".message_box:last").attr("id");

      $.post("home.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID, function(data){
          if (data != "") {
             $(".message_box:last").after(data);     
          }
          $('#last_msg_loader').empty();
      });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           last_msg_funtion();
        }
    });     

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     // Caso scroll seja maior que 150 pixels
     if($(window).scrollTop() < 150){
         $("#coisaEstranha").load('load_first.php');
     }
   }, 60000);

}); 
</script>
```

Página `load_first.php`

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$Busca = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 15");
$Busca->execute();

while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
     $msgID= $fetch['id'];
     $msg= $fetch['content'];
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>" class="message_box" >
   <div>
         <div id="xiao"><?php echo $msg; ?></div><!-- ESTA STRING TRÁS A POSTAGEM! -->   
         <input id="id_post" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_post;?>">
       </div> 
    </div>    
    <?php
}
?>
```

Página `load_second.php`

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];

$Busca = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id < '$last_msg_id' ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 15");
$Busca->execute();

while($fetch = $Busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $msgID= $fetch['id'];
    $msg= $fetch['content'];
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>" class="message_box" >
       <div>        
         <div id="xiao"><?php echo $msg; ?></div><!-- ESTA STRING TRÁS A POSTAGEM! -->    
         <input id="id_post" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_post;?>">
       </div> 
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: O correto seria você testar via PHP se a imagem existe, testando por exemplo com `file_exists`, depende de como está sua estrutura, mais se você fizer em seu CSS `img[src=""]{display:none;}`, imagens com atributos `src` vazios não serão exibidas, veja http://jsfiddle.net/9vm8761c/

Comment: As imagens vem do DB pois são salvas com a tag img e seu respectivo src...tentei usar seu exemplo do Jsfiddle porém não funcionou nem de maneira global nem atribuindo exclusivamente ao ID da div que exibe as postagens :(

Comment: Mostre uma saída do seu código, como fica a tag `img`.

Comment: Asaida renderizada é simples não faço alterações se não limitar a largura a usar o máximo disponivel dentro da div pai que é limitada em pixels...ex: 420px. <img src="caminho/imagem.png" width="100%">

Comment: Só um toque, Lauro, sua pergunta tem código *demais* não relacionado com o problema. Dá um confere em como fazer [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Obrigado pelo "toque', inicialmente coloquei sem código más acho que o pessoal não enteu como retorno e estruturo meu código...quando chegar ao PC de novo vou tentar limpar as classes em divs para ficar mais "enxuto".

Comment: Não seria só fazer uma condicional verificando a existência da imagem antes do (echo $img) <- exemplo  ?

Comment: Infelizmente não @ZebraDoMal ...a string "$" que traz o conteúdo da postagem traz inúmeros elementos e podem haver várias imagens não somente uma.

Comment: Por favor, indente e limpe seu código *sempre*. É melhor para você entender e consertar o código, e **ajuda quem quer te ajudar**, pois não precisa decifrar qual a lógica do programa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O correto, acredito que seria testar via PHP se a imagem existe, testando por exemplo com [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php), depende de como está sua estrutura.

Você pode ainda colocar em seu CSS para que imagens com o atributo `src` vazios não sejam exibidas, exemplo:

```
img[src=""]{display:none;}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vm8761c/)**

Se em seu banco de dados esta gravado a imagem inclusive com a tag `img`, uma solução seria fazer um parse de `HTML` com PHP e obter o `src`, então testar se a imagem existe, exemplo:

```
$img = '<img src="caminho/imagem.png" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($img);
$imagem = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

if(file_exists($imagem)){
    //exibe a imagem
}
```

---

#### EDIT

Outra opção seria reescrever a imagem com htaccess para uma imagem png de 1x1 pixel transparente, exemplo:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) ../img/invisivel.png [NC,L]
```

Comment: Seu exemplo é funcional com html estático porém com tag img vinda do DB e exibida por "print_" ou "echo" não.

Comment: @LauroMoraes editei a resposta, verifique se assim resolve o problema.

Comment: Em seu novo exemplo serviria se fosse o caso de uma imagem de capa que retorna em uma string unica após uma consulta, más meu caso é um elemento html dentro de uma string juntamente com vários outros (outras imagens, textos, iframes de vídeos, etc...). O modelo de postagem estilo feed social.

Comment: Postei em Pastebin caso tenha tempo de dar uma olhada a string "$content" [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ivP81gQw)

Comment: @LauroMoraes, estou no celular agora não consigo testar, mais vc disse q consegue alterar a imagem para uma padrão com htaccess, o q vc poderia fazer é ocultar a imagem padrão com CSS,  `img[src="padrao.png"]{display:none}`

Comment: Fiquei tentado a testar esta dica más o .htaccess leva até o link que no caso não existe mais exibindo a imagem padrão definida nele no lugar do que seria a imagem original. O .htaccess não linka a imagem padrão definida nele no src das imagens que forão excluídas do disco...más obrigado pela ajuda, por hora estou tentando recorrer a DOM com js...se der eu retorno solução.

Comment: @LauroMoraes outra opção seria reescrever a imagem com htaccess para uma imagem png de 1x1 pixel transparente, parece funcionar :P

Comment: Opa amigo, desculpe a demora de retornar resposta a sua solução apresentada. Um png transparente de 1x1 no .htaccess resolveu o problema \o/ ! Poderia anexar esta resposta na sua "resposta" para que eu possa marcar como aceita. Obrigado :)

Comment: @LauroMoraes, que bom que funcionou, editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma imagem padrão em branco e faça uma verificação para ver se o `src` da imagem tem algo, caso não tiver, coloque a imagem em branco.

```
<?php

$imagem = $variavel['imagem_do_banco'];

if($imagem == '' or empty($imagem)){
echo '<img src="imagem_padrao.jpg">';
}else{
echo '<img src="'.$imagem.'">';
}
?>
```

Ou tente colocar um **hidden** no `style` da tag `<img>`

```
<?php

$style = ($variavel['imagem_banco'] == '') ? 'display:none;' : 'display:block';
$image = $variavel['imagem_banco'];

echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style="'.$style.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Agradeço a tentativa de ajuda mas, infelizmente seu exemplo é impraticável dentro do escopo de origem de minhas tags img visto que elas vem juntamente com inúmeros outros elementos e não separadamente em uma única string !

Answer (score 0):

Experimente o seguinte:

```
<?php
function removeEmptyImagesFromHtml($html) {
    $lastUseInternalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($lastUseInternalErrors);

    $imgNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $nodesToRemove = array();
    foreach($imgNodes as $imgNode) {
        if( !$imgNode->hasAttribute('src') || trim($imgNode->getAttribute('src')) === '' ) {
            $nodesToRemove []= $imgNode;
        }
    }
    foreach($nodesToRemove as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
ob_start('removeEmptyImagesFromHtml');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <html>
        <img src="teste.png" />
        <img src="" />
        <img />
        <img src="ola.gif" />
    </html>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
```

A saída de HTML deve estar entre o `ob_start` (que guarda o HTML em memória, sem passar para o browser) e o `ob_end_flush` (que envia para o browser o HTML alterado).

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo, mas parece nao ter funcionado. Carrego conteudo incluindo outras duas páginas (uma de pré-load e outra de carregamento sob demanda) tive conflitos em atribuir seu exemplo em hambas e tentando usar apenas uma para testes tbm pareçe não ter funcionado...não conforme o esperado. Adicionei o code para uma melhor intendimento. Grato.

Comment: Corrigi um erro: estava removendo apenas a primeira imagem, talvez porque alterava o DOM. Coloquei também HTML para teste. A saída é:
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src="teste.png"><img src="ola.gif"></body></html>**
O **ob_start('ob_gzhandler')** antes do **ob_start('removeEmptyImagesFromHtml')** vai criar problemas. Coloque depois, faça uma função com as duas funções ou configure no Apache para comprimir o output quando o browser permite (não dá com todos, por isso atenção com o seu código - tem de validar pelos headers HTTP).